# How to show action buttons for DateRangePicker from material-ui-picker

Tags: material-ui

I am using latest material-ui/pickers v4-alpha7.

Is is possible to show action buttons for the DateRangePicker. I know that they are shown by default for MobileDateRangePicker but can not find the solution for the regular DateRangePicker.

```
function BasicDateRangePicker() {
  const [selectedDate, handleDateChange] = React.useState<DateRange>([null, null]);

  return (
    <DateRangePicker
      startText="Check-in"
      endText="Check-out"
      value={selectedDate}
      onChange={date => handleDateChange(date)}
      renderInput={(startProps, endProps) => (
        <>
          <TextField {...startProps} />
          <DateRangeDelimiter> to </DateRangeDelimiter>
          <TextField {...endProps} />
        </>
      )}
    />
  );
}
```

Br, Igor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From their current docs:

> Date/Time pickers experience is **extremely different on mobile and desktop**. Here is how components will look on different devices. The default DateRangePicker component is responsive, which means that **Mobile or Desktop mode will be rendered according to device viewport**.

You can either use the `DateRangePicker` - which will be responsive, or decide that you prefer to force specific behaviour by using `MobileDateRangePicker` or `DesktopDateRangePicker`.

Source: https://mui.com/components/date-range-picker/#responsiveness

There is no `prop` that you can pass to the `DateRangePicker` to force using the mobile version in order to show the buttons (you can just use the `MobileDateRangePicker` if you need it to work this way).